# Computing representations of $SL_2(\mathbb F_3) \ltimes C_3^2$ explicitly

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am trying to explicitly construct the complex representations of $SL_2(\mathbb F_3) \ltimes C_3^2$, with the natural action of matrices on two-dimensional vectors by multiplication. Here are the facts I have determined:

1. $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$ contains 7 conjugacy classes of sizes 1, 1, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4. The elements in these classes have order 1, 2, 4, 6, 6, 3, 3 respectively.
2. $|SL_2(\mathbb F_3)| = 24 = 3 \cdot 1^2 + 3 \cdot 2^2 + 3^2$ which is the only decomposition into sum of squares, hence there are 3 1D representations, 3 2D ones and a single 3D one.
3. 1D representations can be found by trial and error: choose a complex number of order 2, 3, 4 or 6 and send conjugacy classes into it until you find a homomorphism.
4. The 3D representation can be found by factoring $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$ by its center $C_2$. The factor is $A_4$. $A_4$ acts on a 4-dimensional space by permuting coordinates. This action has an invariant subspace where the sum of the coordinates is zero. Take $P$ a permutation matrix, then the following matrices form a 3D representation of $A_4$ which can be lifted to $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$:
   \begin{array}{ccccc}
   \left(
   \begin{matrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   \end{matrix}
   \right)
   & \times & P & \times &
   \left(
   \begin{matrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
   -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   \end{matrix}
   \right)
   \end{array}
5. The character table is $7 \times 7$ and looks like this (here $\omega^3 = 1$):

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \omega & \omega^2 & \omega^2 & \omega \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \omega^2 & \omega & \omega & \omega^2 \\
2 & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
2 & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
2 & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
3 & 3 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}

6. $SL_2(\mathbb F_3) = C_3 \ltimes Q_8$ with a peculiar action of $C_3$ on $Q_8$. $Q_8$ lies in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd conjugacy class, while there are multiple instances of $C_3$ in $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$.
7. $|SL_2(\mathbb F_3) \ltimes C_3^2| = 216$. The representations of $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$ can obviously be extended to $SL_2(\mathbb F_3) \ltimes C_3^2$. $216 - 24 = 192 = 3 \cdot 8^2$. Also, there are 10 conjugacy classes in $SL_2(\mathbb F_3) \ltimes C_3^2$, hence it remains to find 3 representations of dimension 8.
8. [This book](http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf) lists on page 76 a way to construct a representation of $G \ltimes A$ where $A$ is abelian. It does so by taking an induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}_{G_\chi}^G$ and extending it to a representation of $G \ltimes A$, where $G_\chi$ is the stabilizer of some character $\chi$ of $A$, with $G$ acting on characters by $(g \cdot \chi)(a) = \chi(g^{-1}(a))$. However, the formula for extending does not define a homomorphism.

The formula is $(af)(g) = \chi(g(a)) f(g)$, where $g \in G$, $a \in A$, $f \colon G \to GL(W)$ and $W$ a complex vector space. Let $z_i = (a_i, g_i) \in G \ltimes A, i=1,2$. Then

\begin{align}
z_1 z_2 &= (a_1 + g_1(a_2), g_1 g_2) \\
z_1 &\to \chi(g_1(a_1)) f(g_1) \\
z_2 &\to \chi(g_2(a_2)) f(g_2) \\
z_1 z_2 &\to \chi((g_1 g_2)(a_1 + g_1(a_2))) f(g_1 g_2) \\
\chi(g_1(a_1)) \cdot \chi(g_2(a_2)) &\neq \chi((g_1 g_2)(a_1 + g_1(a_2)))
\end{align}

The problem is that $ag \to g(a)$ is not a homomorphism $G \ltimes A \to A$.

Oops.

---

I would like to find out

1. Is there a way to determine completely the character table and the two-dimensional representations of $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$ without doing a difficult computation such as calculating $\mathrm{Ind}_{Q_8}^{SL_2(\mathbb F_3)} \mathbb C^2$ and then attempting to decompose it into irreducible representations? I know about [this wiki](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_special_linear_group:SL(2,3)), but I would prefer to do this by myself. And it doesn't list the matrices explicitly, only the character table.
2. How can I construct the 8-dimensional representations of the semidirect product? Is the error I've described an easily fixable typo, or is this theorem indeed incorrect?

---

**UPD:** in his book, Serre treats the situation of $G \ltimes A$ (section 8.2). His approach is slightly different, and it works.

I am still looking for an answer to the first question, though.

Comment: This group is also known as a special affine group.  It can be written nicely in terms of matrices.